# Is that statement a well-known result in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, hilbert-spaces

Here is the statement :

> Let $(\{\pm1\}^n,\mathcal{P}(\{\pm1\}^n), \mathbb{P})$ a probability space, $(X_i)_{1\le i\le n}$, $\ n$ random real variables which are mutually independents. For all $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ : $\mathbb{P}(X_i =1)=\frac{1}{2}=\mathbb{P}(X_i = -1)$. Let $(v_i)_{1\le i\le n}$, $\ n$ unit vectors of $E$ (a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space with the scalar product : $E\to \mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto\langle x,y\rangle$).

> We define the random variable $U : \{\pm1\}^n \to \mathbb{R},\ \omega \mapsto \Vert \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i (w)v_i \Vert^2$. Then there exists $(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n) \in  \{\pm1\}^n$ such that : $\Vert\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \epsilon_iv_i\Vert\le \sqrt{n}$. And moreover, if the $(v_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ are not pairwise orthogonals then there exists $(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n) \in  \{\pm1\}^n$ such that : $\Vert\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \epsilon_iv_i\Vert>\sqrt{n}$.

It seems to be linked with Pythagoras theorem for euclidean space. Is this result well-know in probability theory or does this statement have a name ?

Moreover, what would happen if if we took $\{\pm1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ instead of $\{\pm1\}^n$ ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't really understand what the $v_i$ are. Are they unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: You keep saying "$\mathbb{R}$-space vector" but that is not normal mathematical English. We say "real vector space" or occasionally "$\mathbb{R}$ vector space", but the former is preferred unless there is a chance of talking about vector spaces over fields other than $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Alright, now I just need to understand what that "." operation in the norm is and we've got the language issues fixed up. Is that the componentwise product?

Comment: Just putting them next to each other does not solve the confusion, since there is no "normal" multiplication of a vector with a vector.

Comment: The Khintchine inequality might be what you're looking for, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality).

Comment: @Ian it is a vector multiplied by a scalar

Comment: @Michh Thank you, I will dig this !

Comment: Ah ok, the $\epsilon$'s are signs and the $v$'s are vectors. Now the notation makes sense.

Comment: The probability space, the random variables $X_i$,  and the random variable $U$ have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: I think you are mixing up the question itself (which has no randomness) and a suggested solution (which can use randomness to solve the question by noting that if $Z$ is a random variable that satisfies $E[Z]\leq 0$ then there is an outcome $\omega$ such that $Z(\omega) \leq 0$).

Comment: @Michael What would be the main statement for you ?

Comment: @Maman : see my answer, which summarizes my comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simplified statement of the problem is this:

Given $n$ unit vectors $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ on an inner product space with inner product $\langle v, z \rangle$ and norm $||v|| = \sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$, prove

a) There is a vector $(w_1, ..., w_n) \in \{-1,1\}^n$ such that $||\sum_{i=1}^n w_iv_i||\leq \sqrt{n}$.

b) If there is some pair of distinct vectors $v_i, v_j$ such that $\langle v_i, v_j\rangle \neq 0$ then there is a vector $(w_1,..., w_n) \in \{-1,1\}^n$ such that $||\sum_{i=1}^n w_i v_i||> \sqrt{n}$.

---

While this problem has nothing to do with probability, one way to solve it is to define a random vector $(W_1, ..., W_n) \in \{-1,1\}^n$ with i.i.d. entries and use the fact that if $Z$ is a random variable that satisfies $E[Z]\leq 0$ then there is an outcome $\omega$ such that $Z(\omega) \leq 0$.

Comment: Thank you, so is it from Klintchine ?

Comment: @Maman I do not know what your above comment means.

Comment: Is this statement from the mathematician Klintchine ?

Comment: @Maman : I don't know who that is. The statement was posted by you, so, I would think you are the best one to know where it is from.  I just recognized this as a true statement and also one that could be solved using probability.